# submitting a form via jquery removes submit input variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, form-submit, forms

Here's my HTML:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="test" method="get" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="var1" value="true" />
    <input type="submit" name="var2" value="submit" />
</form>
<script>
$("#test").submit();
</script>
```

The resultant request that that makes has var1 in it but not var2. My question is why and what can I do to get var2?

Here's a live demo:

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/dev/submit.php

Comment: var2 is submit button, you only get var1 that's not a problem.

Comment: var2 is a submit button and it will  not post the value, you need to add another input of type hidden/text etc

Answer (score 1):

try: `method="post"` in form or use `<button type="submit"></button>`

Answer (score 1):

A form should submit the value of a submit button only if it's clicked to submit the form (see [HTML5 4.10.22.4 Constructing the form data set](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/forms.html#constructing-the-form-data-set)). Calling the submit method doesn't click the button, so it doesn't submit the value.

The code you've posted will endlessly submit the form, thanks.

You can call the *click* method of the button, but that may not work (i.e. submit the button's value) everywhere:

```
<form id="test" method="get" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="var1" value="true">
    <input type="submit" name="var2" value="submit">
</form>

<button onclick="$('#test')[0].var2.click()">submit form</button>
```

Or, as user3701524 suggests, use *method=post* if that suits.

Comment: "The code you've posted will endlessly submit the form, thanks" No it doesn't - not unless you modify the code that I've posted and if you've done that than I can hardly be held responsible for that. It echo's out the `print_r` output if `$_GET['var1']` is set.

Comment: Copy and paste into a browser, `$("#test").submit();` submits the form, reloads the page, submits the form…

Comment: That's why the live demo I provided at http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/dev/submit.php exited if $_GET['var1'] was set. The code I posted was just intended to give a conceptual overview of what I was wanting to do. If I were to throw in the PHP code that the live demo had than that could confuse people who don't know PHP. And since this question ultimately wasn't a PHP question...

Answer (score 0):

The value on button will only be submitted when u actually CLICK that button. To make it all work nice, I recommend binding to

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    // here you have the button value if it was clicked.
    e.preventDefault(); // optional this prevent default submission.
});
```

either way, calling `$('form').submit()` will **NOT** send the button value because is not triggered by the button itself.

Hope it helps!